# How to insert current date in sqlitedatabase

Tags: android

I want to insert only the current date in sqlitedatabase. To my understanding, the date needs to be an integer. I would like to insert the date in a way in which I can later query the date. How can I achieve that?
Thanks

```
public class MyDatabase{

public static final String KEY_ROWID ="_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME ="persons_name";
public static final String KEY_ADDRESS ="persons_address";



private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PersonsDatabase";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "personsTable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 

                KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT NOT NULL);"

                        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }

}
public long createEntry(String name, String address) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME , name);
    cv.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);

    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't store date values in database, you can only store strings. You can convert current date to string this way:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

...

cv.put(KEY_DATE, sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));
```

You can read date from db this way:

```
String tmpString = curs.getString(curs.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE));

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

Date dateVariable = sdf.parse(tmpString);
```

**Update**

Also you can store timeatamp as long value. For example:

```
cv.put(KEY_DATE, System.currentTimeMillis());
```

To query last 7 days You need to do that:

```
long sevenDaysAgo = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;

Cursor curs = sqLiteDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE, null, KEY_DATE + " > " + sevenDaysAgo, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: While reading the date using cursor, how can I query date for the last 7 days? Thanks

Comment: The better way to use timastamp in your case. I've updated my post.

Comment: Query for the date for last 7 days, I want to get the name inserted during that time,                                      for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
              
           result = result + c.getString(iName) + ",";      
             } //would this be the correct way to query the name.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create column as:

```
col_name TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Ignore col_name while inserting (this will be added automagically). If you want to obtain the date, you do it this way:

```
private Date getDateFromCursor(Cursor cursor) {
    Timestamp dateTime = Timestamp.valueOf(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("col_name")));
    int rawOffset = TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset();

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(dateTime);
    calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, rawOffset);

    return calendar.getTime();
}
```